# android P notification channel sound

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, channel

when we changed target sdk from 27 to 28 we got problems with push notifications.
we still getting them, however without sound and without our vibrations pattern.

```
audioAttribute = AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .build() 
channel.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.annoying_alert), audioAttribute)
```

when I change target version back problem is gone.

Comment: problem is still here even if I use `RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the end we realized that channels are immutable and there is no way to modify them afterward. As a result R file link to the raw sound was changed and there is no way to fix this.
there are only two solutions

- create a new notification channel and link sound as a direct link to the file
- and just don't update target version( it should keep the reference to the R file)